# canvas background makes anchors unclickable

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I've found mixed evidence about whether it's feasible to create a dynamic background with the HTML5 canvas element. Here's a guy who seems to have successfully done it:

http://radikalfx.com/files/anibg/

I have successfully positioned my canvas element as a background, but it has rendered my links unclickable. Here's the situation:

HTML:

```
<div id='container'>

... other header stuff ...
   <canvas id='background'>
   </canvas>

   <!-- Can't touch this *MC Hammer Shuffle* -->
   <a href='#'>test</a>
... footer stuff ...

</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Everything's z-index is now 1 */
#container
{
position: relative;
min-height:100%;
width:100%;
z-index:1; 
}

/* Make the canvas z-index 0 */
#background
{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
z-index: 0;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
 // Onload Draw an ellipse
// I've got jCanvas installed (jQuery plugin) to use the drawArc() method
// This bit can be replaced with whatever test code you want. 
function load()
{
init_canvas();
$("canvas").drawArc({
        fillStyle: "black",
         x: 100, y: 100,
          radius: 50
    });
}

// Make the canvas the appropriate size
function init_canvas()
{
canvas = document.getElementById("background");
    canvas.width = document.width;
    canvas.height = document.height;
    canvasW = canvas.width;
    canvasH = canvas.height;
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: I get the error *Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'drawArc'*. Remember that `$()` returns a jQuery object (if you are using jQuery).

Comment: Is there a specific way you need to set the canvas up to be a background? I feel like the way I'm doing it is a work-around, not a proper implementation

Comment: @FelixKling Do you have jCanvas installed? That's part of the api necessary to use the example stuffs I've given. I'll edit the post to reflect that

Comment: Ah... that's it then I guess ;)

Comment: Posted the edit, mah bad. That piece can be replaced with whatever would assure you that the Canvas is working. Just standard javascript would work. I just want to get into jQuery along with Canvas magic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `#container` in your CSS to give everything else a `z-index` of 1, yet you never put an element `#container` on the page.

Change your HTML to the following and it will work as expected:

```
<canvas id='background'></canvas>
<div id="container">
    <a href='#'>test</a>
</div>
```

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ht6c8/**

Comment: I'll edit the post, but I figured it was implied I would have a container div elsewhere in the code. I'll make that clear. My bad

Comment: Ok, well in that case, make sure that `#background` is not placed within `#container`.

Comment: Oh, I'll give that a shot then!

Answer (score 0):

every element with the `position: absolute` is being placed over other not positioned item, even if other elements are placed in DOM after. So you can just set `position: relative` for your anchor element